# How can I determine which database a replication subscription belongs to?

Tags: postgresql, replication

Following along from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68720250/cannot-drop-subscription-from-postgresql

It seems in order to drop the subscription, you first need to connect to the associated database. However I'm not sure how to determine which database a subscription belongs to?

An example of a subscription I'd like to delete:

```
finder_v2=# SELECT * FROM pg_subscription;
 subdbid | subname | subowner | subenabled |                                            subconninfo                                            | subslotname | subsynccommit | subpublications 
---------+---------+----------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------------+-----------------
   16384 | chris   |       10 | t          | host=localhost user=postgres password=mysecretpassword port=5555 dbname=finder connect_timeout=10 | chris       | off           | {chris}
(1 row)
```

I did a web search for this, as well as reading through some of the postgres documentation but still not able to figure this out.

Comment: If the associated database is connectable, dropping the subscription will automatically connect to it, you don't need to do anything.

Comment: Doesn't the subconninfo column contain the info you want?

Comment: I don't think it does? It gave me an `ERROR:  subscription "chris" does not exist` error when I tried that. And no, subconfninfo seems to only relate to the publication connection details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`subdbid` identifies the database in which the subscription is defined:

```
select *
from pg_database
where oid = 16384;
```

Or join it to pg_subscription:

```
SELECT d.datname, s.subname, s.subowner::regrole::text
FROM pg_subscription s
  join pg_database d on d.oid = s.subdbid;
```